# Button Click inside Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I'm trying to get a helpfulness indicator to work on a page. I can get access to the buttons but I'm having trouble getting the button clicks to increment the total number of clicks. Im using vb code behind.

Here is the code behind I am using to access the buttons and attempt to do some form of calculation with:

```
Protected Sub movies_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles movies.ItemCommand
    Dim yCount As Integer
    yCount = 0
    Dim nCount As Integer
    nCount = 0
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType =
    ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim btnYes As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnYes"), Button)
        Dim btnNo As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnNo"), Button)
        Dim lblResults As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblResults"), Label)
        Dim sArgument As String = CType(e.Item.DataItem, 
                 DataRowView).Row.Item("MovieTitle").ToString
        If btnYes.OnClientClick Then
            yCount = yCount + 1
            MsgBox(yCount)
            lblResults.Text = yCount
        ElseIf btnNo.OnClientClick Then
            nCount = nCount + 1
        End If
        total = yCount + nCount

    End If
    MsgBox(total)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like your `total` variables is a local one. Every invocation of `movies_ItemCommand` creates a new variable named `total` and sets its value to 0. Move declaration outside of the method ie a global private field in your class.

Comment: Thanks Szymonides I tries that but it still doesn't work I'm afraid

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your codebehind? Did you increment `total`?

Comment: I have. I have edited my code above to show what I have in the code behind for this section. I have declared total globally as an Integer.

Comment: In this case both `yCount` and `nCount` should be global variables aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'll take a stab anyway.

I want to say that your global variable gets reset each time the page posts back. You can declare it static (if that works for your purpose), or keep the value in the session or viewstate, or maybe a hidden field or something. For values that I need to persist, I tend to use something like the following:

```
Protected Property PropertyName() As ReturnType
    Get
        If IsNothing(Session.Item("SessionIdentifier")) Then
            Session.Item("SessionIdentifier") = DefaultValue
        End If
        Return Session.Item("SessionIdentifier")
    End Get
    Set(value As ReturnType)
        Session.Item("SessionIdentifier") = value
    End Set
End Property
```